# Access query using DCount takes a long time to run

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Could anyone help me to reduce the query running time for the following query? If it involves VBA that's okay, I just need to get the correct result faster.

```
UPDATE A_Ticket SET 
I_S1_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S1_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S1_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S2_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S2_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S2_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S3_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S3_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S3_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S4_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S4_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S4_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
SR_I_S1_Open = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
SR_I_S1_Received = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
SR_I_S1_Resolved = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] = 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S2_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S2_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S2_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] = 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S3_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S3_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S3_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] = 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S4_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S4_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S4_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] = 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that might speed things up would be to create a saved query named [create_W_Data_summary] to perform the majority of the COUNTs and write them to a temporary table:

```sql
PARAMETERS prm_StDate DateTime;
SELECT 
    [Product],
    [Priority],
    [Type] = 'R' AS [is_Type_R],
    [A_Group] <> '1' AS [A_Group_is_not_1],
    [R_Group] <> '1' AS [R_Group_is_not_1],
    [C_Date] < [prm_StDate] AS [earlier_than_StDate],
    COUNT(*) AS row_count
INTO [W_Data_summary]
FROM [W_Data]
GROUP BY
    [Product],
    [Priority],
    [Type] = 'R',
    [A_Group] <> '1',
    [R_Group] <> '1',
    [C_Date] < [prm_StDate]
```

resulting in a table named [W_Data_summary] containing rows like

```
Product   Priority  is_Type_R  A_Group_is_not_1  R_Group_is_not_1  earlier_than_StDate  row_count
--------  --------  ---------  ----------------  ----------------  -------------------  ---------
Product1  S1               -1                -1                                                 1
Product1  S1                0                -1                                     -1          1
Product1  S1                0                -1                -1                   -1          2
Product1  S1                0                -1                -1                    0          1
```

Then your UPDATE query could total up the appropriate [row_count] values like so

```sql
UPDATE A_Ticket SET 
I_S1_O = DSum("row_count","W_Data_summary","[Priority] = 'S1' AND (NOT is_Type_R) AND (A_Group_is_not_1) AND (earlier_than_StDate) AND [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S1_R = DSum("row_count","W_Data_summary","[Priority] = 'S1' AND (NOT is_Type_R) AND (A_Group_is_not_1) AND (NOT earlier_than_StDate) AND [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S1_Re = DSum("row_count","W_Data_summary","[Priority] = 'S1' AND (NOT is_Type_R) AND (R_Group_is_not_1) AND [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'")
```

If you save that query as [update_A_Ticket] then your VBA code would be something like

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "W_Data_summary"
On Error GoTo 0
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("create_W_Data_summary")
qdf!prm_StDate = CDate(Forms!Home!Txt_StDate)
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("update_A_Ticket")
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
```

Your UPDATE query would still be doing 24 domain aggregate operations for each row in [A_Ticket], but it would be doing them on the [W_Data_summary] table which would presumably have far fewer rows than the [W_Data] table.

### edit re: SQL Server linked table

The above assumed that [W_Data] was an Access table. If [W_Data] is an ODBC linked table to SQL Server then the process is slightly different:

Create a SQL Server stored procedure named [W_Data_rollup]

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[W_Data_rollup] 
    @StDate date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 
        [Product], 
        [Priority], 
        is_Type_R, 
        A_Group_is_not_1, 
        R_Group_is_not_1, 
        earlier_than_StDate,
        COUNT(*) AS row_count 
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                [Product], 
                [Priority], 
                CASE 
                    WHEN [Type] IS NULL THEN NULL 
                    WHEN [Type] = 'R' THEN -1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END AS is_Type_R, 
                CASE 
                    WHEN [A_Group] IS NULL THEN NULL 
                    WHEN [A_Group] = '1' THEN 0 
                    ELSE -1 
                END AS A_Group_is_not_1, 
                CASE 
                    WHEN [R_Group] IS NULL THEN NULL 
                    WHEN [R_Group] = '1' THEN 0 
                    ELSE -1 
                END AS R_Group_is_not_1, 
                CASE 
                    WHEN [C_Date] IS NULL THEN NULL 
                    WHEN [C_Date] < @StDate THEN -1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END AS earlier_than_StDate
            FROM dbo.W_Data
        ) AS whatever
    GROUP BY
        [Product], 
        [Priority], 
        is_Type_R, 
        A_Group_is_not_1, 
        R_Group_is_not_1, 
        earlier_than_StDate
END

GO
```

Create a saved pass-through query in Access named [get_W_Data_rollup]

```sql
EXEC dbo.W_Data_rollup '2013-11-11'
```

(Note that the initial date value is just a placeholder. It will be updated by the VBA code below.)

The make-table query [create_W_Data_summary] simply becomes

```sql
SELECT * 
INTO W_Data_summary
FROM get_W_Data_rollup;
```

The update query [update_A_Ticket] remains as before

```sql
UPDATE A_Ticket SET 
    I_S1_O = DSum("row_count","W_Data_summary","[Priority] = 'S1' AND (NOT is_Type_R) AND (A_Group_is_not_1) AND (earlier_than_StDate) AND [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
    I_S1_R = DSum("row_count","W_Data_summary","[Priority] = 'S1' AND (NOT is_Type_R) AND (A_Group_is_not_1) AND (NOT earlier_than_StDate) AND [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
    I_S1_Re = DSum("row_count","W_Data_summary","[Priority] = 'S1' AND (NOT is_Type_R) AND (R_Group_is_not_1) AND [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'");
```

and the VBA code to "make it go" is

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "W_Data_summary"
On Error GoTo 0
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("get_W_Data_rollup")
qdf.SQL = "EXEC dbo.W_Data_rollup '" & Format(CDate(Forms!Home!Txt_StDate), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("create_W_Data_summary")
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("update_A_Ticket")
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
```

Comment: Gord, I have done a mistake is this line while creating the initial query

I_S1_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"),

Comment: Gord, I have done a mistake is this line while creating the initial query. If it is Re then R_Group <> '1' not Group <> '1'. So i think the create_W_Data_summary query needs to be change and also other. Could you please advise me where i need to change ? I am little confused :-(. Apologies for my mistake.

I_S1_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'")

Comment: @Sathish Please update your question with the corrected query and I will try to update my answer to match.

Comment: Done my changes, for O, R it will be A_Group <> '1' and for Re it will be R_Group <> '1'

Comment: i am getting ODBC syntax error for the below Group By clause

GROUP BY
    [Type] = 'R',
    [A_Group] <> '1',
    [R_Group] <> '1',
    [C_Date] < [prm_StDate]

When i remove the conditions like if i use the below its working

[Type] 
[A_Group]
[R_Group][C_Date] < [prm_StDate]

Comment: i am getting ODBC syntax error for the below Group By

GROUP BY
    [Type] = 'R',
    [A_Group] <> '1',
    [R_Group] <> '1',
    [C_Date] < [prm_StDate]

When i remove the conditions and if i use the below its working

[Type] 
[A_Group]
[R_Group]
[C_Date]

Also the UPDATE A_Ticket  query completed and i am not getting any output in my table.

Also one more doubt in executing, where i need to give the Type = 'R'

SR_S1_O =
SR_S1_R =
SR_S1_Re =

Sorry for chasing you again and again.

Comment: @Sathish It sounds like [W_Data] is an ODBC linked table in Access. If so, then **(1)** What back-end is it linked to? ...Microsoft SQL Server? **(2)** What is the actual name of the table in the back-end database?

Comment: (1) it is MS SQL Server (2) dbo.W_Data

Comment: Gord, FYI It is working now, but i am getting some blanks in some of the rows. I am checking the update_A_Ticket query. Meanwhile i am having one question, will it be possible to execute this within SQL Server itself by creating a single stored procedure because both tables are linked tables (ie W_Data and A_Ticket). So when we create a stored procedure like above to calculate the count and update A_Ticket within SQL Server and will it be quicker than MS Access?. Please advise...sorry for once again for troubling you.

Comment: @Sathish Yes, I am quite sure that a SQL Server stored procedure could accomplish the same result, and it would probably be faster since all of the processing would take place on the SQL Server.

Comment: Gord, thanks for all your help. I will try to create it , please give your support if possible.

Comment: @Sathish It would probably be best to close off this question and then start a new one if need be. The answers to this question are fairly Access-specific.