# Creating a stored procedure in SQL Server to replace an Access DCount() query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ms-access-2010

I have two tables in SQL Server, one is [W_Data] which will have the original data and the other one is [A_Ticket] which will contain the Product and its count for priority and type wise. Currently this table is updated through the following query in Access. Now I am planning to create a Stored Procedure to update [A_Ticket] from [W_Data] since both are SQL Server linked tables in MS Access. Please help me to create a Stored procedure to replace the following query.

(For more background on this requirement, please see the earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20297343/2144390).)

```
UPDATE A_Ticket SET 
I_S1_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S1_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S1_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S2_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S2_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S2_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S3_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S3_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S3_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S4_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S4_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
I_S4_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
SR_S1_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
SR_S1_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
SR_S1_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] = 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S2_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S2_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S2_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S2' and [Type] = 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S3_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S3_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S3_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S3' and [Type] = 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S4_O = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S4_R = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] = 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= Forms!Home!Txt_StDate and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'"), 
S_S4_Re = DCount("*","W_Data","[Priority] = 'S4' and [Type] = 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product]='" & [Product_Name] & "'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With poor knowledge of your DB structure, it will be something like this:

```
create procedure _update_ticket
  @product varchar(max),
  @date datetime
as
begin
  update t set
    I_S1_O = (select count(*) from W_Data where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< @date and [Product] = @product), 
    I_S1_R = (select count(*) from W_Data where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= @date and [Product] = @product), 
    I_S1_Re = (select count(*) from W_Data where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and [Product] = @product), 
    .....
  from ATicket t
  where Product_Name = @product
end
```

**EDIT**
To update whole ATicket (assuming existence of column Product_Name in it):

```
create procedure _update_ticket
  @date datetime
as
begin
  update t set
    I_S1_O = (select count(*) from W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< @date and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
    I_S1_R = (select count(*) from W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= @date and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
    I_S1_Re = (select count(*) from W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
    .....
  from ATicket t
end
```

Comment: Could you please advise me how to give/assign the input for variable @product from W_Data?. For date i will get it from Form like below 

qdf!date = CDate(Forms!Home!Txt_StDate)

Comment: Tried below but getting error while executing

Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure Update_A_Ticket_Count1, Line 0
Procedure or function 'Update_A_Ticket_Count1' expects parameter '[@Product]', which was not supplied.
create procedure Update_A_Ticket_Count1
  [@date] datetime,
  [@Product] varchar(Max)
  as]
  SELECT [@Product] = (SELECT TOP 1 [Product_Name] FROM A_Ticket ORDER BY [Product_Name])
  
WHILE [@Product] is not null
begin
 update t set
    I_S1_O = (select count(*) from W_Data ......
 from A_Ticket t
   where Product_Name = [@Product]
end
go

Comment: @Sathish In this example i assuming that you need to update 1 row in ATicket whith specified product name. If you need to update whole table ATicket then see updated answer.

Comment: why we need [@product] varchar(max)?

Comment: last one question if  name of the field for Product example [Product_Name] = [Product_Name]) , it is not working . giving same count to all rows in a field

Comment: ,last one question if name of the field for Product example [Product_Name] = [Product_Name]) , it is not working . giving same count to all rows in a field

Comment: Excellent working fine, i will accept this answer as useful :-)

Comment: Hi When i execute the above SP with the below function from Access form it is taking long time... waited more than half an hour. When open the pass through query it is updating within few secs. pls advise

Function AppCount()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
On Error Resume Next
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("Get_A_Ticket")
qdf.SQL = "EXEC dbo.Update_A_Ticket_Count '" & CDate(Forms!Home!Txt_StDate) & "'"
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
End Function